# Escaping an error in a for loop and moving to next iteration

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, try-catch

Following is the code that I am trying to use:
data is a huge data frame that I am trying to create and data2 is a small output that is returned for a particular link. These links I am reading from a different data frame called df.

```
data <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(df$Link))
{data2 <- try(get_caption(df$Link[i]), silent = TRUE)
data2$videoId <- df$videoId[i]
 data2$channelId<-df$channelId[i]
data <- rbind(data,data2)
i<- i+1
Sys.sleep(5)
}
```

My issue is that when there is an error which I escape by using try command, data 2 isn't generated and data2$videoID gives an error. I want something that will help me escape the error as well as the following two lines when there is an error.

```
data2$videoId <- df$videoId[i]
data2$channelId<-df$channelId[i]
```

Comment: If you could post exactly what you are trying to accomplish with a sample of the input and expected output data I am sure the answers will be better. I think a `for` loop is not the best way - also there are several problems in your `for` loop - there is no need for `i<- i+1` and read about loop memory pre-allocation in R: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/growing-objects-and-loop-memory-pre-allocation/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be corrected with the use of `tryCatch` instead of `try`. Like this you will have an error condition when one occurs, can test it and proceed accordingly.

```
data <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(df$Link)){
  data2 <- tryCatch(get_caption(df$Link[i]), error = function(e) e)
  if(!inherits(data, "error")) {
    data2$videoId <- df$videoId[i]
    data2$channelId<-df$channelId[i]
    data <- rbind(data,data2)
  }
  Sys.sleep(5)
}
```

An alternative is to use `*apply` loops to run the function `get_caption` and test which ones went well or not. The main advantage is to have an errors list and what to keep created with the same index variable (`bad`). Two for the price of one.

```
data <- lapply(seq_along(df$Link), \(i) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  tryCatch(get_caption(df$Link[i]), error = function(e) e)
})
bad <- sapply(data, inherits, "error")
errors_list <- data[bad]

data2 <- do.call(rbind, data[!bad])
data2$videoId <- df$videoId[!bad]
data2$channelId <- df$channelId[!bad]
```